# Install and configure dfs namespace on standalone windows server

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am running below commands and it creates a share folder but nothing is showing in dfs namespace.
I want to create a folder under namespace, currenly my system is standalone.I need to do using powershell script.

```
mkdir C:\DFSRoots
mkdir C:\DFSRoots\Corp
net share Corp=C:\DFSRoots\Corp
net share Corp
dfsutil root addDom \\serverName\Corp "share drive"
```

Comment: How do you expect to create a domain-based namespace on a standalone server?

Comment: As per wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_(Microsoft) there are 2 types of namespace one we can create in domain other is standalone?  I am planning to do installation first and then bring them to domain ?

Comment: That's putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: So we cannot create a standalone namespace server ? If you have any script related to domain based , I happy to see that as well.

Comment: Sure you can create standalone namespace servers. But AFAIK you cannot put domain-based namespaces on them.

Comment: Yes I tried manually and I am able to create standalone namespace but my requirement is to create via powershell. The only thing is when it asked fro domain we need to mention our local server name ... Please help how to create local namespace .I have tried all the commands on web :(

Comment: [`dfsutil root addstd ...`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2009/05/01/using-the-windows-server-2008-dfsutil-exe-command-line-to-manage-dfs-namespaces/)?

Comment: Thank You very much my friend !!! it is really helpful...